# Assign variable to result of lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I'd like to accomplish something like the following:

```
(clientSinceChoices =  Enumerable.Range(1949, DateTime.Now.Year - 1950)
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem() 
    { 
        Text = x != 1949 ? x.ToString() : "Unselected", 
        Value = x != 1949 ? new DateTime(x, 1, 1).ToString() : null,
        Selected = () => 
        {
            if (x == 1949 && !ClientSinceYearOnly.HasValue)
                return true;
            else if (ClientSinceYearOnly.Value == x)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }));
```

I want the value of `Selected` to be the result of the labmda expression that is defined inline. I know I can accomplish this by assigning the lambda to a variable and then invoking it, but I think that defining and immediately invoking it is "cleaner".

Comment: Looking at the code, "clean" isn't one of the first things that comes to my mind ;P

Comment: @Saeb :( Yeah, you're right. It was cleaner before I added the case for 1949.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, to actually answer your question: you can invoke a lambda "in place" by casting it to a delegate:

```
bool x = ((Func<bool>) ()=>true) ();
```

But in your code there is no need for the lambda in the first place; I don't see why you have a lambda at all. You want to compute a Boolean, so *compute the Boolean*:

```
Selected = (x == 1949 && !ClientSinceYearOnly.HasValue) || 
                         (ClientSinceYearOnly.Value == x)
```

(Also, note that you do not have to check to see if the nullable has a value before you compare it; equality is "lifted to nullable" in C#.)

Second, this query is a mess because you've got a special case in there. I would not write your query like this in the first place. I would rather say:

```
var choices = new List<Item>();
choices.Add(new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = "Unselected",
    Value = null;
    Selected = ClientSinceYearsOnly == null
};

choices.AddRange(
    Enumerable.Range(1950, DateTime.Now.Year - 1951)
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem() 
    { 
        Text = x.ToString(), 
        Value = new DateTime(x, 1, 1).ToString(),
        Selected = x == ClientSinceYearOnly
    });
```

Much clearer. Or, write yourself an extension method that sticks something onto the start of a sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, T first)
{
    yield return first;
    foreach(T item in sequence) 
        yield return item;
}
```

and then:

```
var choices = 
    Enumerable.Range(1950, DateTime.Now.Year - 1951)
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem() 
    { 
        Text = x.ToString(), 
        Value = new DateTime(x, 1, 1).ToString(),
        Selected = x == ClientSinceYearOnly
    })
    .Prepend(new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = "Unselected",
        Value = null;
        Selected = ClientSinceYearsOnly == null
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'll be refactoring that code. Nifty idea with the Prepend; I thought about going that route before, but I didn't think of using yield. Why do you have to cast the lambda as a Func? Is it because the compiler doesn't know whether to treat it as a delegate or an expression without explicitly defining the type? Or am I missing the point there completely?

Comment: Your conjecture is correct; the compiler does not know what kind of delegate to convert the lambda to unless you tell it.

Comment: The "in place" lambda code does not compile for me.  I'm targetting .NET 4.5 so I assume it should work.  The compiler gives several errors such as "Invalid expression term ')'", Invalid expression term '=>', and 4 more.

Comment: Turns out I needed to add some parentheses to your expression to make the compiler happy:
bool x = ((Func<bool>)(() => true ))();

Answer (score 4):

You could always put the conditional in a method and invoke that:

```
public static bool ShouldBeSelected(int x)
{
    if (x == 1949 && !ClientSinceYearOnly.HasValue)
        return true;
    else if (ClientSinceYearOnly.Value == x)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Then you can just use it:

```
        (clientSinceChoices =  Enumerable.Range(1949, DateTime.Now.Year - 1950)
                                        .Select(x => new SelectListItem() 
                                        { 
                                            Text = x != 1949 ? x.ToString() : "Unselected", 
                                            Value = x != 1949 ? new DateTime(x, 1, 1).ToString() : null,
                                            Selected = ShouldBeSelected(x)
                                        }));
```

---

Also, in your case, you could use a series of logical operators since you're returning a boolean (*not recommended* if you don't want the future maintainers to kill you in your sleep):

```
(x == 1949 && !ClientSinceYearOnly.HasValue) || (ClientSinceYearOnly.Value == x)
```

Comment: +1 exactly - the OP is getting caught up in shiny new toy disease.

Comment: @x0n maybe :( I did end up pulling it out into a method. So I guess it's not possible to assign Selected to the value of a lambda that's immediately invoked?

Comment: You probably could if you cast it to Func<bool> but that would be fugly.  Selected = ((Func<bool>)() => { ... }).Invoke() -- oh, I jus saw someone else did that below.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best use for a lambda, but the way you invoke a lambda inline is just by putting parentheses after it:

```
(clientSinceChoices =  Enumerable.Range(1949, DateTime.Now.Year - 1950)
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem() 
    { 
        Text = x != 1949 ? x.ToString() : "Unselected", 
        Value = x != 1949 ? new DateTime(x, 1, 1).ToString() : null,
        Selected = ((Func<bool>)(() => 
        {
            if (x == 1949 && !ClientSinceYearOnly.HasValue)
                return true;
            else if (ClientSinceYearOnly.Value == x)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }))() // <-- the () calls the function
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is functionally equivalent:

```
Selected = 
    x == 1949 && !ClientSinceYearOnly.HasValue ||
    ClientSinceYearOnly.Value == x;
```